# How do I check the assumptions of the Wald test for binomial GLM?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, likelihood-ratio, wald-test

At my statistics course we used LRT to get the p-value of the covariates from a binomial GLM. There was something mentioned about the Wald test assumptions not being met, which results in biased p-values. How can I check if the assumptions of the Wald tests are met, given that I have the model:

```
fit <- glm(leaf_infected ~ botrytis_trt * biochar_trt, data = infection_data, family = binomial)
```

Comment: Better not to do it, it is known to very seldom be fulfilled for logistic regression, with practical sample sizes! It even has a name, Hauck-Donner phenomenon, search this site, and look at the tag [tag:separation].